# I have an error with tokenizing CSV file with NLTK, how would i fix this?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I'm new to NLP and python, although I am sure this code should work, could someone tell me why i'm getting this error and how to fix it?
here is my code:

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

df = pd.read_csv('dev.csv')
df.head()

df['text'][:10]

tokenized_word = word_tokenize(text[4])
print(tokenized_word)
```

The error looks like this...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6cb6d5bc3bd5> in <module>
----> 1 tokenized_word = word_tokenize(text[4])
      2 print(tokenized_word)

NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

Comment: You're not assigning `text` anywhere... do you mean to do `text = df['text][:10]`? Otherwise `df['text'][:10]` does nothing.

Comment: Show the output of `df.head()`, or show the first two or three lines from the csv file.